# Preserving state for removed components in React

Tags: reactjs, components, state

This is a challenge from the React Docs Beta site. The solution I used was not one that they offered at the end of the challenge.
I am wondering if this is bad practice.
To preserve state between removed components I used the same key on the <Form/> component. This seems to work.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [showHint, setShowHint] = useState(false);
  if (showHint) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p><i>Hint: Your favorite city?</i></p>
        <Form key="form1" />
        <button onClick={() => {
          setShowHint(false);
        }}>Hide hint</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Form key="form1" />
      <button onClick={() => {
        setShowHint(true);
      }}>Show hint</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Form() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  return (
    <textarea
      value={text}
      onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt that it's good practice.
Instead I would recommend to **keep** the changing tags in one **single return statement** and **render** them **conditionally**.

Your app component would then look like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [showHint, setShowHint] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      {showHint && (
        <p>
          <i>Hint: Your favorite city?</i>
        </p>
      )}
      <Form />
      <button onClick={() => setShowHint(!showHint)}>
        {`${showHint ? "Hide" : "Show"} hint`}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above example would also minimize code duplication.